# awk not finding a string value with special characters in a csv file

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I'm just trying to find a way to check if a string value exists in a csv column using `awk` command. It works fine except for the strings which contains special characters like `(` or `[`.

It worked for text with no special chars. Then when I tried searching text with special chars it hasn't worked, so I tried to escape these chars but it hasn't worked neither.

So I got a `test.csv` file which contains a row like:

```
"hello","(hello)","this is a test (bye)","Alright"
```

then if I try searching the first field like:

```
text="hello"; awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$1~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

it returns `Alright"`, which is fine.

then if I try searching the second field like:

```
text="(hello)"; awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$2~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

it returns `Alright"`, which is fine too.

then if I try searching the third field like:

```
text="this is a test (bye)"; awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$3~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

it returns nothing.

then if I try escaping special chars like:

```
text="this is a test \(bye\)"; awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$3~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

it returns a message like:

```
awk: warning: the escape sequence '\(' is treated as a simple "("
awk: warning: the escape sequence '\)' is treated as a simple ")"
```

with no results as previous.

Comment: If you want to search for a literal string then prefer `index($3,text)` instead of `$3 ~ text`; and the problem with your regex-escaping is because the backslashes are processed when used in an assignment (`-v`)

Comment: For a CSV with quoted values, I would reach for a special-purpose CSV-parsing library rather than `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focusing solely on the non-matching regex issue ....

The `~` operator says to process the right side of the operation as a regex.  When the right side is a string (or variable containing a string - as in this case), the string is converted to a regex (see [GNU awk - Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)).

In this case:

```
text="this is a test (bye)"
awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$3~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

The comparison (`$3~text`) is converted to:

```
$3~/this is a test (bye)/
```

Here the parens are treated as special regex characters and *not* as literal parens so this is effectively the same as:

```
$3~/this is a test bye/
```

Which does not match the data (which contains literal parens).

To match the literal parens we could escape the parens, eg:

```
$3~/this is a test \(bye\)/
```

But as the OP has discovered it's not so easy to escape those parens when dealing with a (`bash`) variable containing a string (ie, `text="this is a test \(bye\)"`).

Another option would be to bracket the parens, eg:

```
$3~/this is a test [(]bye[)]/
```

Which *can* be encompassed in a variable, ie, the following does work:

```
text="this is a test [(]bye[)]"
awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$3~text {print $4}' test.csv
```

The next (bigger) problem then becomes one of how to reformat (`bash`) variables with the necessary pairs of brackets; keep in mind that there are other characters that also have special meaning within a regex (eg, `.`, `*`, `[` and `]`).

At this point it starts getting really messy when trying to figure out which characters need to be 'escaped' inside of (`bash`) variables.

An easier approach would be to look at a different comparison method that deals with *strings* (instead of *regexes*).  As mentioned in a comment this is where the `index()` function comes in handy.

The `index()` function's 2nd argument is processed as a string (and not a regex) so there's no need to worry about some characters (eg, `(` and `)`) being treated differently/specially.  `index()` will return a `0` if the 2nd argument is not found, otherwise an integer is returned that indicates the location of the 2nd argument. [**NOTE:** `awk` treats a `0` as `false` and any other number as `true`]

This means we can keep our original (`bash`) variable assignment and instead make a small change to the `awk` script:

```
text="this is a test (bye)"                                        # no change
awk -F '","' -v text="$text" 'index($3,text) {print $4}' test.csv
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       # replaces '$3~text'
```

This returns:

```
Alright"
```

**NOTE:** see [GNU awk - String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for more details on various string functions; pay attention to which arguments are treated as *strings* vs. *regexes*

---

So what about that 2nd piece of code?

```
text="(hello)"
awk -F '","' -v text="$text" '$2~text {print $4}' test.csv  # returns Alright"
```

`awk` treats this like:

```
$2~/(hello)/`
```

Which is really:

```
$2~/hello/`
```

Net result is that this evaluates as true because it matches on the literal string `hello` and (basically) ignores the literal parens in the data.

**NOTE:** `text="(hello)"` / `$1~text` would also evaluate as true in this case.

Answer (score 2):

With `-F '","'` your first field value is `"hello`, not `hello` or `"hello"`. That, I think, is what's causing you to think you need to do regexp instead of string comparisons but as you're discovering that's the wrong solution. Using `-F ","` not only leads to your current problems but it's fragile since it'll fail given input like `"head","foo"",""bar","tail"` where the middle field `"foo"",""bar"` contains nested escaped quotes with a comma between them.

**Using GNU awk** for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v text='hello' '
    $1 == ("\"" text "\"") { print $4 }
' test.csv
"Alright"
```

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v text='this is a test (bye)' '
    $3 == ("\"" text "\"") { print $4 }
' test.csv
"Alright"
```

You can do that **with any awk** but you need to write a bit more code:

```
$ awk -v fpat='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' -v text='this is a test (bye)' '
    {
        tail = $0
        $0 = ""
        while ( (tail != "") && match(tail,fpat) ) {
            $(NF+1) = substr(tail,1,RLENGTH)
            tail = substr(tail,RLENGTH+2)
        }
    }
    $3 == ("\"" text "\"") { print $4 }
' test.csv
"Alright"
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information on reading CSV with awk.

If your `text` string can contain backslashes then see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for other ways than `-v` (which interprets escape sequences) to assign your awk variable a value outside of the script.